# Double integral bounded by square

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have this double integral and I am not sure how to use the bound region to generate my limit  bounds..

the double integral is y-2x^2 dA      and it is bounded by |x| + |y| = 1

What do I do to start integrating this and how would I get the bound values from this? I am stuck on every part of this from integrating to coming up with the bounds.

Comment: Why don't you draw a picture of the points $|x|+|y|=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help to draw a picture of your domain. In this case you can choose to integrate over $y$ first, and then (as you will be able to see from a plot), $y$ ranges from 0 to $|x|-1$. You can then split up your integral into 2 domains in x, $(-1,0)$, and $(0,1)$, You then get:

$\int_{-1}^0 \int_0^{x+1} f(x,y) dy dx$ on $(-1,0)$,

$\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} f(x,y) dy dx$ on $(0,1)$,

where $f(x,y) = y-2x^2$ and $dy dx$ means you integrate over y first, then x.The idea here is that you integrate up to one variable to get your function in terms of one variable then you have an absolute integral.

Comment: There is no area with $x$ or $y$ outside $[-1,1]$

Comment: Your right, sorry I will update this.

Comment: $y$ should range from $-(|x|-1)$ to $|x|-1$.