# This shows all double integrals are zero; spot the mistake

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Say we have some integral

$\int_0^{\pi}d\phi_1\int_0^{\pi}d\phi_2f(\phi_1,\phi_2)\ .$

If I make the substitution $\psi_1=\phi_1-\phi_2$ and $\psi_2=\phi_1+\phi_2$, using the determinant of the Jacobian matrix $J_{ij}=\frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial \psi_j}$ I get

$d\phi_1d\phi_2=|J_{ij}|d\psi_1 d\psi_2=\frac{1}{2}d\psi_1 d\psi_2\ .$

For the limits I get $\psi_1^-=\phi_1^--\phi_2^-=0$, $\psi_1^+=\phi_1^+-\phi_2^+=0$, $\psi_2^-=\phi_1^-+\phi_2^-=0$ and $\psi_2^+=\phi_1^++\phi_2^+=2\pi$. So I end up with the integral

$\int_0^0d\psi_1\int_0^{2\pi}d\psi_2 f\big(\frac{1}{2}(\psi_1+\psi_2),\frac{1}{2}(\psi_2-\psi_1)\big)\ .$

But unless there is something singular going on this is zero because of the limits on the first (leftmost) integral. Obviously I'm doing something wrong or one could always make a double integral with finite limits equal to zero. Can someone spot the mistake?

Comment: Your way of changing limits is all wrong. Draw a picture of the domain of integration.

Comment: I tried, but my picture doesn't help me much. Do you have another hint?

Comment: Your change of variables is equivalent to rotating the coordinate system by 45 degrees (and changing the scale by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$), so in the new variables you must still integrate over a square. The crux is that now the square's sides are not parallel to the coordinate axes, so the limits of integration in the inner integral will not be constants but functions of $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$.

Comment: Ok, I get it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557144/double-integral-bounded-by-square